# Representing the result in grayscale

Tags: matlab, colors, grayscale, fuzzy, fuzzy-c-means

I'm working with [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41967-fast-segmentation-of-n-dimensional-grayscale-images) script. The issue is that the result is `coloured` and I want it in `grayscale`, but couldn't figure what to change in the script to do that. Do you know what changes I should perform to get the result as `grayscale`?

Thanks.

Comment: Which script? It contains five

Comment: If you are talking about the variable `Lrgb`, just use `rgb2gray(Lrgb)` to get a grayscale representation.

Comment: @chappjc: Lrgb is eitger `[1,0,0]`,`[0,1,0]` or `[0,0,1]`. Other pixels do not exist. Not sure what rgb2gray really outputs, toolbox is not installed, but probably not a very useful image.

Comment: @DanielR: In DemoFCM.m: `Lrgb=reshape(Lrgb,[size(im) 3]); subplot(1,2,2), imshow(Lrgb,[])`. Definitely an RGB image, assuming the input `im` is an image.

Comment: @chappjc It is an image, which contains only pure red, green ore blue.  The grayscale version will be something around .33 for each pixel (not sure how matlab converts).

Comment: @DanielR Got you. Anyway, `rgb2gray` has a different formula based on visual perception of the intensity of colors, so it would be actually be more like 0.3, 0.59, 0.11 for those R, G, B values. So, I would actually go with your answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

Check the Demo, there is a variable "L". It contains a matrix which represents the clusters, thus only the values 1-3 exist. For example `(L-1)./2` maps cluster 1 to gray value 0, cluster 2 to gray value 0.5 and cluster 3 to gray value 1.